# Bootstrap-datepicker onClose event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have two text inputs and I have bind a bootstrap date-picker to both of them. I want to fire an event when a date is selected. I can't use the dateChange because it is firing unnecessary events while doing so. So I want to set an event like onClose to fire an ajax call. But the issue is that when I select the date and closes the datepicker it doesn't call the ajax but when I reopen it and then change the month by clicking the arrow the ajax is being called.

```
   $('.filter_date').datepicker({
        onClose: function () {
              var form_data = [];
              form_data = originacion_ranking_data()
              if (form_data.length != 0){
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/visual_component/plot',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {'form_data': JSON.stringify(form_data)},
                  success: function(data){
                    if (data != false){
                      $('#tableContents').val(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)));
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
          }
  });
```

```
<%= text_field_tag :start_date, params[:start_date], name: 'daterange', class: "form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker date_range filter_date",size: "16" %>

<%= text_field_tag :end_date, params[:end_date], name: 'daterange', class: "form-control form-control-inline input-small date-picker date_range filter_date",size: "16" %>
```

Please help.

Comment: Maybe. on first `onSelect` trigger `form_data.length` is not `0` and when you reopen it then the `form_data.length` is set to a value more than 1.
Could you post what are we doing in `originacion_ranking_data()` function.
Also, does this function returns something on the initial call ?

Comment: I dont think that's the case because I just tried putting a debugger in it but it's not even going to the debugger inside the onClose event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "onClose" event use "hide" event 
as documented in [Bootstrap Evnets](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

Comment: Not working i tried ```console.log('anything')``` even that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong but this worked now. Thanks :)